# Can I use 'Trigger Email ' extension of Firebase without a "from" email address?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions, mailaddress

I have a domain, but I don't have Email address yet.

I want to use 'Trigger Email' of Firebase for my domain only, is that possible?
There is an item called 'Default FROM address' in the setting of 'Trigger Email',
I think that an email address is necessary.

Does anyone know how to set up 'Trigger Email' without an email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup an SMTP service provider which sends the emails on your behalf.

Firebase lets you set a `'Default FROM address` but the SMTP provider may filter out emails that do not meet their quality criteria.

Usually / Often one has to confirm with the SMTP provider that one is the owner of the "From address", sometimes the domain is enough.

This is a measurement against spammers using their services.

So it is more a question of what your SMTP provider accepts.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
I'm using Sendgrid.
Does it mean that you can send an email to sendgrid even if I use an email address that I can't actually use, as long as you authenticate the domain to sendgrid, and it will be displayed as the sending name to the other party?

Comment: @ggg Maybe. As I wrote that depends on the policy of Sendgrid,, the SMTP provider. You need to check their docs to understand if this is allowed .. or if you actually need a working email-address.